# CSS class is not getting applied to table row

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here are the css classes that were used:

```
.table-striped>tbody>tr:last-child>td,
.table-striped>tbody>tr:last-child>th>.total_row_dark {
  background-color: #76767b !important;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
}

tr.campare_row span {
  background-color: #76767b;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 6px 18px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.campare_row>td {
  vertical-align: middle!important;
}
```

These classes are supposed to be used for the following table row in here:

```
<tr class="campare_row total_row_dark" ng-repeat="location in vm.rwsTableData | filter : 'Summary'" ts-repeat>
  <td> </td>
  <td class="text-left">{{location.locationName}}</td>
  <td class="text-right light-blue">{{(location.waterDemand == vm.constant.NO_WATER_SUPPLY)?'-':location.waterDemand | number:2}}</td>
  <td class="text-right light-blue">{{(location.waterSupply == vm.constant.NO_WATER_SUPPLY)?'-':location.waterSupply | number:2}}</td>
  <td class="text-right light-blue" ng-if="location.waterDemand != vm.constant.NO_WATER_SUPPLY && location.waterDeficit != vm.constant.NO_WATER_SUPPLY">{{(location.waterDeficit == vm.constant.NO_WATER_SUPPLY)?'-':location.waterDeficit | number:2}} ({{(location.waterDemand != 0)?((location.waterDeficit*100)/location.waterDemand):0 | number:2}}%)</td>
  <td class="text-right light-blue" ng-if="location.waterDemand == vm.constant.NO_WATER_SUPPLY || location.waterDeficit == vm.constant.NO_WATER_SUPPLY">{{(location.waterDeficit == vm.constant.NO_WATER_SUPPLY)?'-':(location.waterDeficit | number:2)}}</td>
  <td class="text-right light-orange">{{vm.getStressValue(location.locationStressIndicator)}}</td>
  <td class="text-right light-orange">{{location.impactedPopulation | number}}</td>
  <td class="text-right light-blue">{{location.numOfTankersAsOfToday | number}}</td>
  <td class="text-right light-blue">{{location.numOfTankersForToday | number}}</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

According to the class description the last row in table should be changed to the mentioned background color, text color and font-weight respectively. But it is not changing and the last row is in the color of the whole table. How to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you show what the table structure is too?

Comment: It does as this fiddle shows: https://jsfiddle.net/4tvovto7/1/ - can you show us the resulting table? Have you missed the class name? Or the tbody?

Comment: Please provide us with a fully reproducible example... We need the <table> too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work for last row

```css
.table-striped>tbody>tr:last-child>td,
.table-striped>tbody>tr:last-child>th>.total_row_dark {
  background-color: #76767b !important;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
}


tr.campare_row:last-child {
  background-color: #76767b;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 6px 18px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
.campare_row>td {
  vertical-align: middle!important;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr class="campare_row total_row_dark" ng-repeat="location in vm.rwsTableData | filter : 'Summary'" ts-repeat>
  <td> </td>
  <td class="text-left">{{location.locationName}}</td>
  <td class="text-right light-blue">{{(location.waterDemand == vm.constant.NO_WATER_SUPPLY)?'-':location.waterDemand | number:2}}</td>
  <td class="text-right light-blue">{{(location.waterSupply == vm.constant.NO_WATER_SUPPLY)?'-':location.waterSupply | number:2}}</td>
  <td class="text-right light-blue" ng-if="location.waterDemand != vm.constant.NO_WATER_SUPPLY && location.waterDeficit != vm.constant.NO_WATER_SUPPLY">{{(location.waterDeficit == vm.constant.NO_WATER_SUPPLY)?'-':location.waterDeficit | number:2}} ({{(location.waterDemand != 0)?((location.waterDeficit*100)/location.waterDemand):0 | number:2}}%)</td>
  <td class="text-right light-blue" ng-if="location.waterDemand == vm.constant.NO_WATER_SUPPLY || location.waterDeficit == vm.constant.NO_WATER_SUPPLY">{{(location.waterDeficit == vm.constant.NO_WATER_SUPPLY)?'-':(location.waterDeficit | number:2)}}</td>
  <td class="text-right light-orange">{{vm.getStressValue(location.locationStressIndicator)}}</td>
  <td class="text-right light-orange">{{location.impactedPopulation | number}}</td>
  <td class="text-right light-blue">{{location.numOfTankersAsOfToday | number}}</td>
  <td class="text-right light-blue">{{location.numOfTankersForToday | number}}</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see you are using bootstrap `table-striped` and maybe its style overrides your custom style. So to ensure add `!important` and check if it shows up. (using !important is not very good practice in general)